# Существуют ли генераторы кода преобразующие idl в mock-оболчки?

Tags: c++, mock, idl

При внедрении unit-тестов в проекте мы столкнулись с необходимостью подделывать множество COM-объектов внутри тестов, при этом для каждого объекта нужно создавать mock-оболочку вручную. Также при добавлении новых методов или изменении существующих приходится вручную вносить изменения в mock-оболочку.
Есть ли инструменты для автоматизации этих процессов? Например по idl сгенерировать mock-оболочку.